# PyCharm interpreter adding

Tags: python, pycharm

I try to use my python 3.6 environment in the anaconda. Its path is "~/anaconda/envs/py36". It works fine except I cannot add new package. It shows "nothing to show".

I have added "https://pypi.python.org/simple", and when I use the system default python3, there shows something. Therefore I think it should be an issue in my environment.

When I add the environment, in the directory I saw there are python(application), python3.6(document). I don't know which I should select. If I select python3.6, it will change to python in the path, and they don't look like the same file.

Need your help!

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Configuring your interpreter in pycharm as above will allow PyCharm code inspection to highlight if imported packages cannot be found and will also allow you to jump to code in installed packages.

In order to install new package into your environment, you need to open a terminal, activate your conda environment: `activate py36` and then run `conda install <package-name>`. Thereafter you can reopen the settings and the newly installed package should be listed as installed under that interpreter.